# django - Invalid block tag: 'add_pinned_status', expected 'else' or 'endif'

Tags: django, nginx, django-templates

I get the following error when serving my django application using Nginx+FastCGI

`Invalid block tag: 'add_pinned_status', expected 'else' or 'endif'`

Oddly, the site works just fine when I'm serving using the Django development server. It also works with Nginx most of the time, but the error randomly appears and reappears with refreshes. Any idea what the problem could be?

EDIT: Here's the code, just to clarify that there's NO hanging if statement.

```
{% extends 'master.html'%}
{% load thumbnail %}
{% load tags %}

{% block 'title' %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block 'content' %}
<div id="feed" class="content">
    {% for book in books.object_list %}
    <div class="book_preview">
         <div class="thumbnail">
             <a href="/book/{{ book.id }}/{{ book.get_slug }}/">
             {% if book.cover_image %}
             {% thumbnail book.cover_image "120" as im %}
             <img src="{{ im.url }}" alt="Python for Software Design"/>
             {% endthumbnail %}
             {% else %}
             <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}default_thumb.jpg" alt="Python for Software Design"/>
             {% endif %}
             </a>
         </div>
         <div class="book_details">
             <h2 class="book_title">
                <a class="book_profile_link" href="/book/{{ book.id }}/{{ book.get_slug }}/">{{ book.title }}</a>
                {% if user != book.uploader %}
                <a class="shelf_adder {% add_pinned_status request book.pk %}" href="/shelf/{{ book.id }}/toggle/?next={{ request.get_full_path }}" title="Toggle shelf status"></a>
                {% endif %}
             </h2>
             <h3 class="book_subtitle">
             {% if book.subtitle %}
                 {{ book.subtitle }}
             {% else %}
                 <a href='/book/{{book.id}}/edit/#subtitle'>Provide subtitle</a>
             {% endif %}
             </h3>
             <h3 class="book_authors"> by {{ book.author.filter|join:", " }}</h3>
             <div class="book_description">
             {% if book.description %}
             <p>
                {{ book.description|truncatewords:25 }}
             </p>
             {% else %}
             <p class="message">No description available. Create one.</p>
             {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="book_links">
            <a href="/book/{{ book.id }}/{{ book.get_slug }}/" class="book_profile_link" title="Book profile">
                Book profile
            </a>
            <a href="http://{{ book.homepage }}" class="book_website_link" title="Book website" target="_blank">
                Book website
            </a>
        </div>
        <p>Points: {{ book.shelf_additions }}</p>
        <div class="book_tags">
            {% if book.topics.all %}
                {% for topic in book.topics.filter %}
                    <a href="/topic/{{ topic }}/" title="Browse this topic">{{ topic }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                 <a href="/book/{{ book.id }}/edit/#topics" title='Click to add'>no topics added&#9785;</a>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="pagination">
        {% if books.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ books.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}
            <span class="current">
                Page {{ books.number }} of {{ books.paginator.num_pages }}
            </span>
        {% if books.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ books.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div> 
{% endblock %}
```

The problem starts on the line after the `if user != book.uploader` statement, which as you can see is terminated with the appropriate `endif`. I suspect it may be some sort of timeout but I'm not entirely sure. Keep in mind, it works sometimes but randomly stops when using Nginx. It works flawlessly with the dev server.

Answer (score 3):

Django gives that error when you have an unclosed templatetag. In this case an `{% if ... %}` templatetag.

As to why it only happens in certain scenarios, it might be inside a conditional tag itself, so it's not always processed, but I think Django processes the whole template despite what's going on conditionally or not. It might also be possible that there was some mistake in updating your production site and it's using a different/older version than your development site.

Regardless, the error is the error. Find the unclosed templatetag, and you'll solve it across the board.

**UPDATE**: The alternative is that the `add_pinned_sites` templatetag is undefined. Assuming it is in fact loaded in `{% load tags %}`, make sure that that templatetag library is available in all running environments, i.e. it literally exists on the server. If it is in fact there, make sure you completely reload your Nginx+FastCGI environment, or just reboot the server to be completely sure.

Comment: I just updated the question with the code. The if statement is terminated but if you can see any other problem, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Chris. It's a custom tag I use to add the class "pinned" to certain elements, so I'm sure it's defined and loaded - the desired effect occurs when it's working. I reloaded Nginx quite a few times. It's annoying because I've thought and counterchecked all your suggestions. It's been working for the last few hours so I'm trying to recreate it. Thanks for your time though. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Is "tags" the actual name of the tag library that holds `add_pinned_sites`? Might be worth changing it to a clearer name-- just wondering if it's possible you're seeing import collisions between that and another tag library (like Django's built-in tags).

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it's been working okay the last couple of hours, so I can't tell if it's had any effect. What I'm trying to understand is the randomness - wouldn't a naming collision prevent the import from happening during each request? Plus, I never had the problem when using the development server, only with nginx. Maybe I should phrase the question differently to highlight this. It's all quite frustrating. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the answer to that would require someone smarter than me. I totally get the frustration with the random nature of it. The thing to remember when seeing "random" behavior with a computer is it's almost always something you messed up. Computers don't do random.

Comment: Haha. Fair enough. I vaguely remember reading someplace about poor programmers attributing errors to malice, so I'll try keep that in mind. Thanks anyway.